# Trigonometric sum and residues

Tags: cv.complex-variables, closed-form-expressions, trigonometric-sums

I am interested in the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^k 2\biggl[\sin\biggl(\frac{n\pi}{2k+2}\biggr)\biggr]^{-2g}
$$
where $k$, $g$ are integers. It is not too hard to show that this can also be expressed as
$$
-1-2\pi i\underset{t=0}{\operatorname{Res}}\biggl[\sin\biggl(\frac{\pi t}{2k+2}\biggr)\biggr]^{-2g}\frac{1}{e^{2\pi i t}-1}.
$$

I also want the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^k 2(-1)^n\biggl[\sin\biggl(\frac{n\pi}{2k+2}\biggr)\biggr]^{-2g}
$$
but this one — I have not been able to express in a simpler form. Is there a representation similar to the previous one? Or even better, an even simpler representation, for both (not necessarily using residues)?

Comment: I posted this on math.SE last week (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4408711/590756) but didn't get any feedback. Hopefully it is not off-topic here.